# Applying config transofrmation

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, config-transformation

sorry for such kind of question but I've spent too much time on it.
I have an app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <userSettings>
    <tbp.qa.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="ServiceUri" serializeAs="String">
       <value>localhost</value>
     </setting>
   </tbp.qa.Properties.Settings>
 </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

How to change the 'value' with config transformation, I have tried the following and it doesn't change anything:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <userSettings>
    <tbp.qa.Properties.Settings>
      <add name="ServiceUri" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
        <value>localhost1</value>
      </add>
    </tbp.qa.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The config transformations are working with web.configs by default (at least in VS2010) have you set up your project properly? http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.hu/2010/05/applying-xdt-magic-to-appconfig.html

Comment: I am using SlowCheetah VS extension

Comment: Ok, then you have your original config the element with the name `setting` but in your translation  `add`. Should it be? `<setting name="ServiceUri" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
        <value>localhost1</value>
      </setting>`

Comment: omg, that was so easy one, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config file transformation XML structure should match original config file's XML structure.

So in your config you have the element with the name `setting` but in your transformation file you have the element with the name `add`.

So change your transformation element from `add` to `setting` and it should work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <userSettings>
    <tbp.qa.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="ServiceUri" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
        <value>localhost1</value>
      </setting>
    </tbp.qa.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```